# S3 secure file access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

We have one application that upload images, videos, documents, etc. to different folders in an S3 bucket. From another application (UWP app used by many users in different devices), need to access these files in S3 at different times. We need to make these file access secure, so that only the app users can access these files.

As I understand, we can't use IAM since they should be able to access these file by clicking on something in the app directly, without login to AWS login page.

Is Pre-signed URLs the only option we have? Are there any other options?
As I understand, we will have to create Pre-signed URL for each file through a server. Sometimes, users might have to download 100s of files at the same time. So generating so many Pre-signed URLs might make things slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URLs are *definitely* the way to go.

They do not take time to generate. They can be created in a couple of lines of code, without requiring a call to AWS. (It's basically generating a hash.)

Whenever a user wants to access a private object, or whenever the app wants to reference a private object, simply generate the pre-signed URL for it. This keeps private objects secure, while allowing the application to grant time-limited access to objects. Just generate them on the fly!